# nginx fails to listen on specific IPv6 address

Tags: nginx

Ubuntu 20.04.3
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Hello,

I just followed a simple procedure to set ngnix to listen to a specific IPv6 address https://geekflare.com/enable-ipv6-nginx-apache/ and we encountered an error. Bellow are some relevant info:

```
ip a |g inet6
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    inet6 fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
    inet6 fe80::42:d3ff:feaf:2ad/64 scope link
```

change /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to listen to IPv6 address, note the '[]' were included:

```
listen [fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f]:80 default_server;
```

no other servers listen on p:80:

```
lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
```

and succesfully fails:

```
nginx[16359]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f]:80 failed (22: Invalid argument)
```

solved:

```
ping fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f%wlp4s0
PING fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f%wlp4s0(fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f%wlp4s0) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f%wlp4s0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from fe80::6e35:7039:2681:db1f%wlp4s0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
```

Thanks!